# Node ACS 404 Not found response code to Java http client

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, express, titanium

I am working on a project in which there is a Java scheduler which is a HTTP Client and send xml as data to my node application. In index function of application.js I have written my logic to receive the xml and convert the respective xml to json but when I run my app then I am getting 404 response code from acs but the same is working when I am sending request from browser. Please suggest me what I am lacking in this. I am posting both java http client and node acs code.

**Java HTTP Client Code is**

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:port/");
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
    httpCon.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
    pw.println(xmlString.toString());
    pw.flush();
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
```

**Following is my ACS index function:**

```
    function index(req, res) {
        console.log("TEST *********************************");
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log("Data arrived");
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log('POSTed: ');
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end();
        });
    }
```

**I am runnig the code as:** `acs run --port 7654`

From above code I am getting 404 response code in my java http client but if I write the same node logic in a simple js file as:

```
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log("Data Arrived");
        });
      req.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
      });
    }).listen('7654', function(){
    console.log("Server Connected to : "+ 7654);
    });
```

and run the same as `node <jsfilename>` then it is working fine and sending 200 OK response to java http client.

**1-** Am I missing something in Node ACS app?

**2-** Do we need to configure http server in node acs app because if I write following logic in my application.js file then its working also in node acs:

```
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log("Data Arrived");
        });
      req.on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
      });
    }).listen('7654', function(){
    console.log("Server Connected to : "+ 7654);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The Java scheduler HTTP request is POST request and in the NodeACS app for index method I haven't mentioned method attribute. Now I mentioned **"method":"POST"** then its working fine.